# Chrome is ignoring the rounded corners of my menu on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with Chrome ignoring the rounded corners of my menu on hover. This works in Firefox as well as to round the corners (in chrome) before the hover, however on hover my corners square up. Am I missing something? My HTML consists of a standard ul.

```
#nav > ul > li:first-child a:hover {
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px !important;
-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius-topleft: 4px !important;
-border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
background: url(../images/menu-back-hover.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector for webkit browsers (i.e. chrome) should be:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:  4px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  4px;
```

Comment: WOW... I've done this a thousand times. I can't believe I missed that. It did fix it though. Definitely goes to show how much an extra pair of eyes can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following applied to the parent element with the border radius applied to kick webkit back into line for me:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```

Another option is to wrap the element in two border radius parents.

Seems hacky to me, but far better than the double wrap option – interested to hear other solutions.